# How to read excel files dynamically in a source file into different dataframes in python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, dynamic, python-multithreading

```
excel_TSMS_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/TMP/TSMS.xls', sheet_name='TSMS', dayfirst = True)
excel_Ratecard_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/TMP/Ratecard.xls', sheet_name='Ratecard')
excel_ONCall_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/TMP/On Call Report.xls', sheet_name='On Call Report')
excel_OverTime_df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/TMP/Over Time.xls', sheet_name='OT')
```

Here I have 4 files, I want to create 4 dataframes, like N files N dataframes uniquely. Kindly help

Hi suppose in one scenario the source consists only two like tsms , ratecard in that time create two data frame .how many files in source location that many data frames on reading the Excel data ...kindly help in this case

Comment: Added updated comments .. kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Create two lists, one for file names and one for dataframe names, and empty dictionary

```
dataframe_names = ["TSMS","Ratecard","ONCall","OverTime"]
file_names = ['C:/TMP/TSMS.xls', 'C:/TMP/Ratecard.xls','C:/TMP/On Call Report.xls','C:/TMP/Over Time.xls']

dataframes = {}
```

Then iterate over the lists together (make sure they are the same length) and everytime you open an excel file as a dataframe, add it to the dictionary

```
for index,name in enumerate(file_names):
    df = pd.read_excel(name)
    df_name = dataframe_names[index]

    dataframes[df_name] = df
```

This should work for any number of excel files as long as you keep the two original lists the same length and positions

Comment: Hi suppose in one scenario the source consists only two files like tsms , ratecard in that time it should only  create two data frame .how many files in source location that many data frames on reading the Excel data ...kindly help in this case

Comment: That's what this code snippet does. If you put two excel files and dataframe names in the lists, it will provide you two dataframes

Comment: Thanks Amit , but i kept the 2nd file as ratecard and first file as TSMS. when i check im getting only first file output . i think in the 2nd loop it is getting overwritten, Sorry to ask , could you please help i need to get the two outputs like df_tsms , df_ratecard as dataframes